# Is it possible to insert another value from database with existing value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to insert or append another value from database cell with existing data?

Example table:

```
     tbl_name
------------------
|  id  |  Name  |
-----------------
|   0  |  Jones |
|   1  |  Bryan |
|   2  |  Fate  |
------------------
```

For example I want to add `, james` (on table row `1` column `name`). The result must be:

```
------------------------
|  id  |  Name         |
------------------------
|   0  |  Jones        |
|   1  |  Bryan, james |
|   2  |  Fate         |
------------------------
```

Query:

```
insert into tbl_name (name) Values (, james) WHERE id = 1
```

This query does not work.

Comment: You want to `update`

Comment: Storing non-atomic values as string is sign of poor design. You should consider proper 1:M relationship or at least store it as array/JSON type.

Comment: Is id a unique column?

Comment: @forpas Yes its a primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for change existing content You can use  update

```
 update my_table  
 set Name  = concat(name , ', james')
 where id = 1
```

anyway the use of comma separated  value is often based on bad design  ..  try take a look at mysql json  fields  try a normalization for multiple values

Comment: Thank you. I've been thinking about that for almost 3 hours, I am trying to insert another value for the school year taken in  student evaluation system and my mistake is very simple and it take me three hours. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `UPDATE`:

```
MariaDB [db]> update tbl_name set text=concat(text, ", james") where id=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [db]> select * from tbl_name;
+------+--------------+
| id   | text         |
+------+--------------+
|    0 | Jones        |
|    1 | Bryan, james |
|    2 | Fate         |
+------+--------------+
```